# Another 6 points circle associated with a triangle?

Tags: geometry, circles, conjectures

Consider a triangle *ABC* and a point *D*. For each of the triangles *ABD, BCD, ACD* construct the inscribed and circumscribed circles.

**Conjecture**: *For any triangle *ABC* there always exists a special location of *D*, so that six intersection points of these six circles are concyclic.*

Is this actually true or not?

This construction gives us 12 intersection points , but we are only interested in the "orange" ones and not in the "green" ones. In other words, we only consider the first intersection points of the arches *ADB,BDA,BDC,CDB,ADC,CDA* with the inscribed circles.

[Geogebra dynamic sketch.](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/ynyzjwm4)

[image: K,L,M,N,O,P belong to a circle.]

Comment: As far as I can tell the center of the "KLMNOP-circle" is not the point D. It might be a Classic triangle center or hopefully a new one.

Comment: @dodoturkoz I usually check this site when there is a clear construction leading to a point. But in this case only an approximate location of D can be found. However I checked the first 20 centers in the encyclopedia+ the centers of some known circles and D is not one of them.

Comment: I also noticed it while writing my comment (that's why I deleted it), and started looking for a construction of the point :)

Comment: @YNK I do no claim that in this sketch the point D is located in the exact position that allows this circle to exist. I only speculate that there might be a way to find the exact location of the point D, so this circle exists.

Comment: I misunderstood that the point $D$ shown in your sketch was obtained using a construction. My earlier comment is therefore out of place. I deleted it.

Comment: I intend to delete this question, because apparently it is not good. However I found the clear construction of six point circles: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213766/new-method-for-constructing-six-point-circles

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

[image]

This can be true. For equilateral triangle the center of this circle in on incenter (I)of the triangle because of symmetric quantity of vertices. In isosceles triangle the center of this circle is on the bisector of $\angle BAC$ as shown in figure (a). In other types the center of this circle has a distance from I,  and it is not on any of the bisector of angles A, B and C as shown in figure (b).

Comment: it looks like for acute triangles this circle might indeed exist, but I must admit that for obtuse triangles the construction appears unlikely.